# LINQ Union between two tables with the same fields and then returned in a collection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, devforce

I have given up trying to create a linq query to retrieve a sql server view which is a union between two tables. I will now try to create a linq union.

I have two views, MemberDuesPaid and MemberDuesOwed. They have the same fields in both; (BatchNo, TranDate, DebitAmount, CreditAmount, ReceiptNo, CheckNo, SocSecNo).

I also have a helper class in my application which is called MemberTransaction. It has all the same properties.

How how do i do a union between the two tables where socSecNo = the ssn passed in? I want to union the two tables and return an IEnumerable collection of MemberTransaction. After the two tables are unioned together i want to have the collection that is returned ordered by trandate in descending order.

Comment: Like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in a Linq Union query:

```
var infoQuery =
    (from paid in db.MemberDuesPaid 
    select new MemberTransaction() {
        BatchNo = paid.BatchNo,
        TranDate = paid.TranDate,
        DebitAmount = paid.DebitAmount,
        CreditAmount = paid.CreditAmount,
        ReceiptNo = paid.ReceiptNo,
        CheckNo = paid.CheckNo,
        SocSecNo = paid.SocSecNo})
    .Union
        (from owed in db.MemberDuesOwed
        select new MemberTransaction() {
        BatchNo = owed.BatchNo,
        TranDate = owed.TranDate,
        DebitAmount = owed.DebitAmount,
        CreditAmount = owed.CreditAmount,
        ReceiptNo = owed.ReceiptNo,
        CheckNo = owed.CheckNo,
        SocSecNo = owed.SocSecNo});
```

That should return you a set with everything combined into a single list.

[Edit]

If you want distinct values, you can do something like this after the above statement (you can do it inline if you bracket everything, but this is simpler to explain):

```
infoQuery = infoQuery.Distinct();
```

The variable `infoQuery` will by this time be populated entirely with objects of type `MemberTransaction` rather than the two disparate types in the union statement.

Comment: `Union` already removes duplicate values.  It's a set based operation, and as a result it returns a set as a result.  Sets don't contain duplicate values.  Adding `Distinct` afterwards is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got two collections, one representing each view:

```
var paid = new List<MemberDuesPaid>();

var owed = new List<MemberDuesOwed>();
```

Convert both collections above to instances of the third class before performing the union:

```
var everyone
    = paid.Select(x => new MemberTransaction { BatchNo = x.BatchNo, ... })
          .Union(owed.Select(x => new MemberTransaction { BatchNo = x.BatchNo, ... }))
          .Where(x => x.SocSecNo == ssn)
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.TranDate)
          .ToList();
```

Now you've got a collection of `MemberTransaction`, but there's nothing to indicate how one `MemberTransaction` equals another. So if you just run the above, you'll end up with *everything* from both collections in the result, instead of a true union.

You have to tell it what makes two instance equal, by implementing `IEquatable<T>` on the `MemberTransaction` class.

```
public class MemberTransaction : IEquatable<MemberTransaction>
{
    public int BatchNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime TranDate { get; set; }
    public decimal DebitAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditAmount { get; set; }
    public int ReceiptNo { get; set; }
    public int CheckNo { get; set; }
    public int SocSecNo { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MemberTransaction other)
    {
        return BatchNo == other.BatchNo
               && TranDate.Equals(other.TranDate)
               && DebitAmount == other.DebitAmount
               && CreditAmount == other.CreditAmount
               && ReceiptNo == other.ReceiptNo
               && CheckNo == other.CheckNo
               && SocSecNo == other.SocSecNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does seem a little overly complex.  You can get the result without modifying the existing classes using Linq :)

Comment: Yes it will return all rows, but in this case the data sources are independent so I would assume that is what the OP wants.  :) (I was going to suggest appending `Distinct()` but I haven't tested it).

Comment: When I test it I only get distinct records returned.

Comment: Oh, I should have said that I bracketed the entire query (ie, both halves of the union), then ran `Distinct()` on that.  That way you're working apples with apples of the same type of `MembershipTransaction` and therefore comparison will work.